# How to select 6 random records from table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My `portfolio_controller.rb` has an index method like this:

```
def index
  @portfolio = PortfolioItem.all
end
```

How can I specify in the condition that the code in this block should be executed 6 times? In other words, how can I access exactly 6 values from the `@portfolio` object in my view, using a loop? This is what I have so far:

```
<% @portfolio.shuffle.each do |portfo| %>
```

Comment: There's no condition here.

Comment: Do you want to run the whole loop 6 times or what?

Comment: Yes, I need to run it 6 times.

Comment: Wrap it in another loop then. `6.times do ...`

Comment: I'm curious to know why you want to run this loop 6 times.

Comment: I'm new, I have data in the database and I need to output random 6 values.

Comment: I want the loop to output only six values.

Comment: @AndKop *I need to output random 6 values* --This is a great example of [**an XY problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It is always better to for what you're trying to *achieve*, not for help on a specific implementation blocker (but do also show what you've tried so far!)

Comment: What is `@portfolio`? Do you want 6 unique random values, or could there be repeats? If there are fewer than 6 items in `@portfolio`, then what result do you want?

Comment: I have a database, it can have an unlimited number of values, I need to print only 6 of them and not more. If they are less than 6, then just output as much as there is, but there can not be less of them and forget that there may be less of them, there is no such condition.

Comment: @ portfolio is a variable that holds the values from the database, here it is in the controller, @portfolio = PortfolioItem.all

Comment: `@portfolio = PortfolioItem.all` --- Right, thank you. Please write that in the original question, as it is the most important piece of code you've shown, yet it's buried in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `all`, followed by `shuffle`, is a bad solution for two reasons.

A slight improvement would be to use `sample(6)` instead of `shuffle.first(6)`, as this removes a step from the process.

However, the bigger issue here is that `Portfolio.all.<something>` (where the `<something>` method requires converting the data into a ruby `Array`) will fetch **all** of the data into memory - which is a bad idea. As the table grows, this will become a bigger performance issue.

A better idea is to perform the "random selection" **in SQL** (with the `order` and `limit` methods), rather than in ruby. This avoids the need to fetch other data into memory.

The exact solution is database-specific, unfortunately. For PostgreSQL and SQLite, use:

```
Portfolio.order('RANDOM()').limit(6).each do |portfolio|
```

Or for MySQL, use:

```
Portfolio.order('RAND()').limit(6).each do |portfolio|
```

You could define this as a helper in the `Portfolio` model - for example:

```
class Portfolio < ApplicationRecord
  # ...

  scope :random_sample, ->(n) { order('RANDOM()').limit(n) }

  # ...
end
```

And then in your view:

```
@portfolio.random_sample(6).each do |portfolio|
```

Comment: Thanks, but there will not be much data, it will not affect the process in this project, but thanks, it will help me in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can something like this :

```
 <%(1..6).each do |i| %>
     <% #your statements %>
 <%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<% @portfolio.shuffle.each_with_index do |portfo, index| %>
  <%if index <= 6%>
    <p><%= portfo.title %></p>
  <%end%>
<% end %>
```

Or You can do it as

```
<% @portfolio.shuffle.take(6).each do |portfo| %>
    <p><%= portfo.title %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes, the second is much better.